# Difference between PowerPc and MPC82X instruction set

Tags: assembly, powerpc, instruction-set

I have started learning Assembly for PowerPC and came across MPC82x core which is built around powerpc core with QUICC Engine which is a separate RISC core.

Now I when looked into the instruction set of MPC82x  found it different than that of traditional that of PPC.

For example

```
add rD,rA,rB
```

But PowerPC register are from r0,r31.

What are these rD,rA,rB resister?

Is there any difference exist between normal PowerPc Core and MPC82x Core?

Comment: rD, rA, rB look like placeholders in your typical CPU manual. D, A and B are variables, substitute numbers 0..31. The manual is saying that this command acts on registers (as opposed to memory locations or constants). D probably means destinations, A and B are typical generic names for variables. There's probably a register guide in the beginning of the manual - see and make sure your core has all same registers as a vanilla PPC (with maybe more for QUICC).

Comment: The D, A, and B also typically are referenced in the instruction encoding so you can see where in the encoding the destination register and operand registers live.

Answer (score 1):

No difference really.   Look at the specification:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Architecture

MPCxxxx range of PPC are from Freescale, and others like PPC440 are from AMCC (used to be IBM).

If u are interested in the history, here is the link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PowerPC_processors